# git commit -m "1 page" *** Please tell me who you are

Tags: git

I ran the following command:

```
$ git commit  -m "my web page"

Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <(null)>) not allowed
$
```

Question: what should i do to upload in git?

Comment: This is a bunch of console input/output with no real question surrounding it.

Comment: You should do what it says. Run those commands to set your identity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Arreane@Arreane-PC.(none)')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433970/unable-to-auto-detect-email-address-got-arreanearreane-pc-none)

Answer (score 1):

Please run the following commands with the real details in place of: "you@example.com", "Your Name" and it should all be fine.

```
1) git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
2) git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```