# while iam commiting git commit -m "first commit" it says tell me who you are how can i handle this

Tags: git

while iam commiting git in my hyper terminal 
command:
git commit -m "first commit"
it says "please tell me who you are"
looks like it asking me my email and password
fatal: unable to detect email address

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git commit -m "1 page" \*\*\* Please tell me who you are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331452/git-commit-m-1-page-please-tell-me-who-you-are)

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup your Git identity. See [Git manual](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup#_your_identity).